# Scrolling surface background in sprite.js(canvas)

Tags: javascript, canvas, sprite

I'm making a tile-based browser game using `Sprite.js` to interact with canvas. https://github.com/batiste/sprite.js/

Here is what I got now(PC version has a larger visible area):
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3c-cmWUVrc

It is not easy to redraw every tile each frame because of performance, so I tried to make a scrolling surface background using `scrolling.js` that comes with `sprite.js`. There is an example here http://batiste.dosimple.ch/sprite.js/tests/test_scrolling.html The example works, but it seems like `ScrollingSurface.update` is buggy or there is something I'm missing.

What I tried to do is to draw 5x5 tiles and after 5 seconds draw another 5x5 tiles near the first ones. But it draws only the first ones. And `surface.update()` only updates the position of surface. Here is my code https://github.com/Sektoid/sprite.js/blob/master/tests/test_scrolling.html (You need also to set this.divider = 1.0 in `scrolling.js` if you want to avoid drawing the same tiles 4 times.) There aren't any sprite.js-forums like with the other sprite- and game-engines have, but it is fast and very useful. Take a look at it! And help me please :)